# getting garbage JSON from stack-overlfow api in node.js

Tags: json, node.js, stack-overflow

I am searching for a question using stackoverflow API.
Here is my code:

```
app.get('/sof',function(req,res){
  var ark;
  request("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=relevance&q=python%20best%20practices&site=stackoverflow", function(error, response, body) {
    ark = body;
    console.log(body);
  res.send(ark);
  });
});
```

But, I get garbage values bot in browser and in logs.

How can I can resolver this issue? Everything else is running fine.

I am also using body-Parser:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

EDIT:
here is code that worked as explained by @Wainage in comments.

```
app.get('/sof', function(req, res){
    request.get({ url: "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=relevance&q=python%20best%20practices&site=stackoverflow",
                  gzip: true },
        function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);       // I'm still a string
        body = JSON.parse(body); // Now I'm a JSON object

        res.json(body); // converts and sends JSON
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got tripped up by the callback. The `res.send` will fire before the result is in.

```
app.get('/sof',function(req,res){
  var ark;
  request("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=relevance&q=python%20best%20practices&site=stackoverflow", function(error, response, body) {
    ark = body;
    console.log(body);
    // res only when you get results

    //res.send(ark);
    res.json(body); // converts and sends JSON
  });
});
```

should work.

EDIT: (include gzip deflation for this specific question)

Per the [StackExchange docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/compression) their results are served back gzip'd (makes sense). You need to tell request that is the case.

```
app.get('/sof', function(req, res){
    request.get({ url: "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=relevance&q=python%20best%20practices&site=stackoverflow",
                  gzip: true },
        function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);       // I'm still a string
        body = JSON.parse(body); // Now I'm a JSON object

        res.json(body); // converts and sends JSON
    });
}
```

Comment: that just worked. thanks. but still i am getting garbage value. How can i ca avoid that?

Comment: try `res.json(body)` or `ark`. I'm not sure why you use `ark`? You doing any work on the object?

Comment: yes, will do work with ark. I tried what you said, still getting error. I think this time, it simply logged res in json. i mean there were no question. I tried: 'console.log(res.json(body));
    res.send(res.json(body));'

Comment: @ARK4579 The `console.log(res.json(body))` won't do what you think and you only need `res.json(body)`. `res.json` converts to JSON and does the send

Comment: @ARK4579 I've modified my answer.

Comment: @ARK4579 Does the `console.log` print out the correct info?

Comment: nopes. both console.log and browser are printing garbage even with modified answer.

Comment: I am also using body-Parser.

Comment: @ARK4579 Updated answer. StackExchange uses gzip to deflate response. You need to tell request to deal with it.

Comment: thanks sir. thanks. its working. :) thanks again for quick reply.

Comment: @ARK4579 No problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: I don't understand why is request not applying gzip by itself. The server sends header correctly.